R rasterImage creates a white background when rotated on windows machine, not on mac
When I rotate an imported png image, a white background is added around the "box" the image is in. This happens on windows machine (R 4.3.2) but not on Mac (R 4.2.2). Both have 'png' version 0.1.8.
This is the code run on both machines (loading two basic blue and red colored rectangles):
library(png)

plot.new()
plot.window(xlim = c(0 , 10), ylim = c(0, 10)) 

# blue background
blue.rect <- readPNG("Desktop/rastr_test/blue.png")
rasterImage(blue.rect, 0, 0, 10, 10)

# red boxe
red.rect <- readPNG("Desktop/rastr_test/red.png")

# not rotated
rasterImage(red.rect, xleft = 1, ybottom = 4, xright = 3, ytop = 6, angle = 0)

# rotated
rasterImage(red.rect, xleft = 6, ybottom = 4, xright = 8, ytop = 6, angle = 45)


Here is the result on Mac (expected):

Here is the result on Windows:

How can I remove the white background on Windows?

Thanks for the edits, for some reason I was unable to add the images to the body...
